# C: How to create a cycle of fscanf to assing elements of a file to a structure

Tags: c

I need to create a function that copies elements from a file to a structure.
I am having trouble creating a cycle to assign the second line of code, and third... until an integer is assign here game->words[b].name[c]. Would it be better to use a function to read integers, characters, and to read a series of characters?

```
int loadgame(GAME *game){                                            
FILE *fptr;
int ch,a,b=0,c=0,i=0,j=0;

fptr = (fopen("saveGame0.txt", "r"));
    printf("Error opening file");
    exit(1);
}
else{
    for(a=0;a<2;a++){
        while((ch = fgetc(fptr)) != ';'){
       game->players[a].name[i]=ch;                                     
        i++;    
        }

        fscanf(fptr, "%d", &game->players[a].points);  

        fseek(fptr,1,SEEK_CUR);                     
        while ((ch = fgetc(fptr)) != '\n'){                 
            game->players[a].hand[j].letter = ch;
            j++;
        }
    }
    fscanf(fptr,"%d", &game->word_count);
    fseek(fptr,1,SEEK_CUR);
```

I AM HAVING TROUBLE IN THE PART BELOW.
Next I need to find a way to repeat what is below, for every line of the file, until an integer is assing in the first while cicle to game->words[b].name[c]

```
            while((ch = fgetc(fptr)) != ';'){
                game->words[b].name[c]=ch;
                c++;                                    
            }
        fscanf(fptr,"%c", &game->words[b].orientation);

        fseek(fptr,1,SEEK_CUR);
        fscanf(fptr,"%d", &game->words[b].row);         
        fseek(fptr,1,SEEK_CUR);

        fscanf(fptr,"%c", &game->words[b].col);         
        fseek(fptr,1,SEEK_CUR);

        fscanf(fptr,"%d", &game->words[b].points);
        fseek(fptr,1,SEEK_CUR);
        fscanf(fptr,"%d",&game->words[b].player);

        fseek(fptr,1,SEEK_CUR);
    }

}
fclose(fptr);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Any program that is using `fseek` to read what should be a simple sequence of data, and pays no attention to the return values fom file input functions, perhaps needs a rewrite.

Comment: Sure, can you help me.

Comment: I can't see you terminating with `'\0'` any data items that appear to be reading a string. But really, please try to isolate the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Show some examples of the expected input, and the actual input.

Comment: Having trouble with input and _not_ checking the return values of `fscanf()`, `fseek()` is like going to the doctor wearing [earmuffs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earmuffs) and asking why one is sick.  Check the return values of the input functions.

Comment: I checked the values with pritf like these        printf("%c", game->words[b].name[c]=ch);

Comment: That is not checking the return value of the function.  Use something like `if (1 != fscanf(fptr,"%d", &game->words[b].row)) {puts("Failed"); exit (-1);}` for each `fscanf()`.  For `fseek()`, only a return value of 0 is OK.

Comment: Note that `fscanf` and `fseek` return a value *unrelated to the actual data*, as the **function value**. So if you expect to read one format field with `fscanf` that function should return `1`, when it successfully writes data to the pointer argument.

Comment: The values are correct, but I can only see them for the first line of the file, I can't find a way to do the second part of my code return the values of the next lines.

Comment: And you still don't want to check the return value of the functions?

Comment: In those `fseek(fptr,1,SEEK_CUR);` statements. Do you know that the `scanf` family typically ignores whitespace (except `%c`)? Time to read the man page? Or do some little test exercises to see how it all works?

Comment: I checked and it returned Failed.

Comment: It does not return `Failed`. `fscanf` returns the number of arguments that were converted. Or does "it" mean somemthing else?